# What is the correct way to write less code when multiple ID have same code?

Tags: css, less

I am trying to convert css to less for some code in my project.

I have below code css:

```
#broker_upload_doc .broker_personal_form .well,
#broker_upload_agr .broker_personal_form .well {
    padding: 2em 2em 0 2em;
}
```

Now If I convert it to Less, it becomes:

```
#broker_upload_doc {
    .broker_personal_form {
        .well {
            padding: 2em 2em 0 2em;
        }
    }
}
#broker_upload_agr {
    .broker_personal_form {
        .well {
            padding: 2em 2em 0 2em;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question, is it the only way to convert this code or any other way is there when I have same code under multiple IDs? It seems I am writing more code in Less instead of using css.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the elements with IDs would share a common class like `.broker_upload`. So it's efficiently organizing your HTML and has less to do with CSS/Less. You could then do this:

```css
.broker_upload {
    .broker_personal_form {
        .well {
            padding: 2em 2em 0 2em;
        }
    }
}
```

And fwiw, you of course can still do this (though it seems obvious?):

```css
#broker_upload_doc,
#broker_upload_agr {
    .broker_personal_form {
        .well {
            padding: 2em 2em 0 2em;
        }
    }
}
```

(On a side-note, Sass has the [`@at-root`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root) directive which would let you do it in yet another way. But afaik Less is missing this feature.)